# HTML5 layout issue with select list and buttons

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to layout a few `div` elements. The `div` element hosts a `select` element and three buttons. While i don't want to set a specific size for buttons, I wish the `select` list to fully occupy the remaining space.

[image: List is stretched but without spacing]

As you can see, I kind of get the list to stretch but without spacing. I tried to force padding through CSS without luck. I am certainly missing something.

here is the code:

```css
#presets {
    display: flex;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: auto;
}

#presets select {
    width: 100%; 
}

#presets button {
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="presets">
      <select>
          <optgroup ng-repeat="item in qo.presets">
               <option>{{item.name}}</option>
          </optgroup>
      </select>
      <button>RM</button>
      <button>ED</button>
      <button>AD</button>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your hints,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `margin` instead of `padding`:

```css
#presets {
  display: flex;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: auto;
}
#presets select {
  margin-right:5px;
  width: 100%; 
}
#presets button {
  margin-right:5px;
}
#presets button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="presets">
  <select>
    <optgroup ng-repeat="item in qo.presets">
      <option>{{item.name}}</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <button>RM</button>
  <button>ED</button>
  <button>AD</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to layout a few `div` elements. The `div` element hosts a
>   select element and three buttons. While i don't want to set a specific
>   size for buttons, I wish the select list to fully occupy the remaining
>   space.

This is exactly what the [**`flex-grow`**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/) property of flexbox is designed to handle.

The `flex-grow` property specifies how much of the *remaining space* in the container a flex item should consume.

By simply applying `flex-grow: 1` to the `select` element, it takes up all available space.

```
#presets select {
    flex-grow: 1;
    /* width: 100%; REMOVE, not necessary */
}
```

> As you can see, I kind of get the list to stretch but without spacing.

Simply specify a margin for all flex items:

```
#presets > * {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fb1hh78u/)

*A couple of notes:*

- The way `flex-grow` works, if you would have applied `flex-grow: 1` to all flex items, it would have distributed the remaining space evenly among each item. See [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fb1hh78u/1/).
- Instead of `flex-grow: 1`, you can use [`flex: 1`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/). This shorthand property allows you to specify the `flex-grow`, [`flex-shrink`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-shrink/) and [`flex-basis`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-basis/) properties all in one declaration. See [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fb1hh78u/2/).